# Should multiple Spring Boot App instances running behind a load balancer work with spring CAS user authentication?

Tags: cas

I have a Spring Boot Application I am working on that uses CAS authentication. I have CAS working fine however once I start more than 1 copy of the application behind a load balancer the app fails to authenticate.

The app takes the user off to CAS and returns to the home page where once authenticated the user should see the main interface.  But instead when it returns from CAS the spring security authenticated check still thinks the user isn't authenticated.

If I reduce my instances down to 1 it starts working fine again.

I am running this app behind an F5 load balancer so I am trying to figure out if there is some missing configuration on the F5 or if there is something I need to do in my app to deal with the switch from one server to another etc.  I assume this is causing the issue but I want to keep my app stateless and not rely on making the F5 sticky for a given user.  Actually I even tried setting the feature on the F5 but still get the same behavior so not sure what is really happening once more than 1 app instance is running.

My understanding was that this should just work because I have server.use-forward-headers=true configured.

Am I missing some other CAS, Spring Boot Server, or Spring Boot Security settings that are necessary to make this work?

Should this be working with CAS authentication.

I am using Spring Book 2.0.4.RELEASE
I am using spring-security-cas-client 3.0.8.RELEASE

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using by your CAS server? If you are using OAuth / SAML, then you might need to set your F5 load balancer to enable "session persistence".

Comment: I am using cas20ServiceTicketValidator which I think is SAML 2.  Following these instructions.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/cas.html  I have discovered the problem is that Spring Boot is creating a session using the JSESSIONID cookie.  So like you say I have to configure the F5 with session persistance.  But I was hoping to make my application stateless so I am trying to figure out if that can be compatible with CAS.  I find examples of making Spring Security Stateless but never with CAS as the authentication method so not sure if they are compatible.

Comment: "I was hoping to make my application stateless" in that case I don't know if it is at all posible, maybe the CAS source code relies on session persistence, so you can't make it stateless? I don't have access to an F5 now so I can't test it, see if other have any idea...

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I think I just need to do as you suggest and set session persistence.  I found a blog online about creating a stateless implementation but so far the code they provided doesn't work.  The example wasn't for CAS it was for a basic in memory login as most examples are so I had to translate a little.

Comment: Ok then, I will right it as Answer for future users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue.  It seems the Spring Boot Security defaults to a session based security so you need to implement your own Stateless Security to get this working in a stateless manner.

Thanks to this blog post and some additional help from the blog post author I was able to get this working perfectly in Spring Boot 2.x

Checkout the post, it's interesting and works perfectly.

https://www.dedicatedcode.com/posts/stateless-authentication/

Thanks to others who provide answers that sent me in the correct direction to find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with multiple cas server cluster. When your spring boot application is looking for a valid ticket it fails to authenticate.
CAS has a support for these kind of situation try reading the link below

https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/installation/Hazelcast-Ticket-Registry.html

If the above solution works you have to add a dependency for the support and update your property files
Hope this helps

Comment: Interesting, what makes you think the problem is with CAS?  I am pretty sure the problem is on the Application side.  We have other stateless applications successfully working with our CAS instance so I think it is correctly configured.  I don't really have as much control over our CAS instance as that is maintained in another department.  I only have control of the application servers.

Comment: Look at this way. When user first logs in cas will authenticate the user and will generate a ST ticket. Now everytime request goes your cas-client(spring-boot app). The cas client will go and ask cas that is this ticket valid.

Comment: If the ticket is validated by cas server then your cas-client app will allow accessing the resources otherwise will redirect back to cas login screen.
Check this link for spring-boot cas client configuration https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cas-sso

Comment: If this was the issue wouldn't I have the problem when I was running only 1 copy of my application as well?  The problem only occurs when I start a second copy of my application and only happens when the requests switch from one application to the other based on the load balancer configuration.  If I change the load balancer to persist sessions the problem also goes away.  This too seems to indicate to me that CAS cluster is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **OAuth** / **SAML** / **Delegated** Authentication, then you might need to set your F5 load balancer (or any load balancer) to enable "**session persistence**" in order for CAS server to function normally.